# How to scroll an overflowing div inside a web page

Tags: java, css, selenium, scrollbar, overflow

Is there a way to scroll the scrollbar of a div inside a web page? To be more exact, I'm trying to automate the scrolling of up and down of an instagram post e.g https://instagram.com/p/9D5Ir3CY3D/?taken-by=bentomonsters. However, as the scrollbar might be hidden using CSS property, I might not be able to detect it as the scrollbar is not an element.

Below is the css style (from firebug) of the scrollbar.

```
.-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__comments {
    margin-left: -24px;
    margin-right: -24px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsSidebarVariant {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
} 
.-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__comments {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, 
blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, 
img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, 
center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, 
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, 
figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, 
time, mark, audio, video {
    border: 0 none;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

I have tried ways such as

```
WebElement commentscroll = dr.findElement(By.className("commentsSidebarVariant"));

jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollTop;", commentscroll);

jse.executeScript("$(\"#commentsSidebarVariant\").animate({ scrollTop: \"100px\" })");  

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];", commentscroll);

WebElement commentscroll = dr.findElement(By.cssSelector(".-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsSidebarVariant"));               

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop;", commentscroll);
```

and none of them works as the scrollbar does not even move.

Comment: Are you asking - *is it possible to make an element scroll without using an input device (mouse, trackpad, touch, etc...)*? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030571/use-js-jquery-to-scroll-a-divs-content-that-has-overflow-scroll-applied

Answer (score 1):

I use the following methods for scrolling an overflowing element using pure JS and checking if I reached scroll end.
When reaching scroll end you need to scroll back up with a similar method since you might have started scrolling from any position.

The methods below are reference code, not the entire solution:

```
    // Returns true if scroll succeeded, false otherwise
    private boolean scrollDownOverflowElement(WebElement element, int lazyLoadingGracePeriodMillis) {
        long scrollTopBefore = (long) javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollTop", element);
        javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].clientHeight", element);
        if (isAtEndOfScroll(element)) {
            // Wait for 1 second to give additional async results a chance to load (e.g. select2 drop downs)
            sleep(lazyLoadingGracePeriodMillis);
        }
        long scrollTopAfter = (long) javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollTop", element);
        return scrollTopAfter != scrollTopBefore;
    }


    // Returns true if element is at end of scroll, false otherwise
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight
    private boolean isAtEndOfScroll(WebElement element) {
        // scrollTop is the number of number of pixels scrolled down from the top (0 when scrolled all the way up)
        // scrollHeight is the height of the scroll view of an element. It includes the element padding but not its margin.
        // clientHeight is the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin. (the displayed size of an overflow element)
        final boolean isAtEnd = (boolean) javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollHeight - arguments[0].scrollTop === arguments[0].clientHeight", element);
        return isAtEnd;
    }
```

Comment: im sorry, i do not understand how your reference code would help in solving my question as it checks whether the element has reached to the bottom of scroll but as i mentioned i was unable to know the name of the scrollbar element due to it being a css property that will only appear if the text box is "filled".

Comment: The solution scrolls thru Javascript, not the scroll bar. It works whether the scroll bar appears or not, based on the element properties

Comment: i tried implementing the scrollDownOverflowElement(WebElement) in this way `scrollDownOverflowElement(commentscroll);` in the main method, but there is this error of **non-static method scrollDownOverflowElement(WebElement) cannot be referenced from a static context**. Is this not the right way to call the method?

Comment: You can't call instance methods from a static context. You can change scrollDownOverflowElement to static as long as it's not using instance members. You will need to provide javascriptExecutor as a method param, and change downstream methods called by this one to static as well. You will also need to change sleep to Thread.sleep.

Comment: if it is not to too much to ask, could you comment on the reference code as i have a little difficulty understanding what each line is supposed to do. thank you. @eitan